# Dapr logs export to Azure Monitor

Tags: logging, azure-application-insights, azure-api-management, dapr, azure-monitor

We have **Azure API Management** self-hosted on **Azure Kubernetes Services**. As we need to collect the logs from the container for monitoring purposes (some of the logs are sent to `stdout` only and not to the Application Insights). For this reason, we've enabled **Dapr** to collect the logs from `stdout` in `values.yaml` file:

```
dapr:
  enabled: true
  app:
    id: apim-test-scus
  config: tracing
  logging:
    useJsonOutput: true
    level: debug
```

But we are facing issues sending the logs to **Azure Monitor**. We've tried to use the **Open Telemetry Collector** but it only collects the traces, but not the logs.

ConfigMap of **Open Telemetry Collector**:

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
      http:
  zipkin:
    endpoint: 0.0.0.0:9411

processors:
  batch:

exporters:
  azuremonitor:
    instrumentation_key: *****************
  logging:
    loglevel: info
extensions:
  health_check:
  pprof:
    endpoint: :1888
  zpages:
    endpoint: :55679

service:
  extensions: [pprof, zpages, health_check]
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [zipkin]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [logging, azuremonitor]
    logs:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: []
      exporters: [logging, azuremonitor]
```

But it seems like the Dapr doesn't send the data using the `Open Telemetry Protocol`. We can see the logs in the **Dapr Dashboard** but the **Open Telemetry Collector** doesn't receive any logs from Dapr.

Is it possible to send the logs from **Dapr** to **Open Telemetry Collector** using `otlp` or other protocol?

Answer (score 2):

This question is a bit old so apologies if you have already resolved it.

As far as I know, Dapr captures and displays output from stdout, but it doesn't actually emit those logs for other tools to collect. The simplest solution would be to install **FluentD** on your cluster and configure it to forward logs to your collector.

There is actually guidance on setting up **FluentD** with Dapr in the [Dapr Docs](https://v1-10.docs.dapr.io/operations/monitoring/logging/fluentd/).

Unfortunately, those docs configure FluentD to export to an **Elasticsearch** endpoint - so you will need to update the configuration in *fluentd-config-map.yaml* to define a 'match' for your OpenTelemetry collector.